# Put specific rows at the end of data frame depending on column value

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a data frame that looks something like:

```
df =

col1    col2    col3
--------------------
10      56.4    78.2
20      45.6    23.3
30      12.1    26.0
40      55.4    22.9
50      10.1    98.3
```

Then I have a regular list that contains:

```
list1 = [10, 30]
```

Is there any way to then sort the data frame, so that the values in `list1` corresponding to the values in `col1` will be "sorted" towards the end, such as:

```
df_sorted =

col1    col2    col3
--------------------
20      45.6    23.3
40      55.4    22.9
50      10.1    98.3
10      56.4    78.2
30      12.1    26.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `key` parameter in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
list1 = [10, 30]

df = df.sort_values('col1', key=lambda x: x.isin(list1))
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
1    20  45.6  23.3
3    40  55.4  22.9
4    50  10.1  98.3
0    10  56.4  78.2
2    30  12.1  26.0
```

If order is important one idea is use `merge` with helper `DataFrame` and then `concat`:

```
list1 = [10, 30]

df1 = df[~df['col1'].isin(list1)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list1}).merge(df)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
1    20  45.6  23.3
3    40  55.4  22.9
4    50  10.1  98.3
5    10  56.4  78.2
6    30  12.1  26.0
```

---

```
list1 = [30, 10]

df1 = df[~df['col1'].isin(list1)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list1}).merge(df)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
0    20  45.6  23.3
1    40  55.4  22.9
2    50  10.1  98.3
3    30  12.1  26.0
4    10  56.4  78.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pd.concat` with `sort_values`:

```
>>> pd.concat([df.loc[~df['col1'].isin(list_1)], df.loc[df['col1'].isin(list_1)]].sort_values('col1'), ignore_index=True)
   col1  col2  col3
0    20  45.6  23.3
1    40  55.4  22.9
2    50  10.1  98.3
3    10  56.4  78.2
4    30  12.1  26.0
>>>
```